# Re-potted my Sciadopitys verticillata, and now its turning orange - what should I do?

Tags: containers, repotting, evergreens, pines

[image]I have a Sciadopitys verticillata on my balcony (Berlin, DE). I potted it out of its nursery pot, now the tips of the needles are turning orangey/ brown.

Will it recover once its settled in, or should I fertilize or add something to the soil. I have read I should water it once a week in a pot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do change colours some in winter.  There is a variety names 'Winter Green' that has been bred to stay dark green all winter long.
Do not fertilise in winter.  Fertilise again in early spring.

Comment: Thanks you, good know was about to fertilize .